# Why window resize with rotation disturbs UI layout include image in kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

After an image rotated and window resized, the image moved no assumed location. In my assumption, image always moves to the center of left side pain. Please tell me solution.

This code realize to generate window with both pain(area window)s at left side and right side. The left side was assumed as a menubar. The right side was assumed to manipulate an image with rotating. If you move mouse on window, the image will be rotated according to your mouse distance.

### MyEnv.

- MacOS: 10.14.5
- Kivy: 1.11.1
- Python:3.6.8 by conda.

```py
from cmath import sqrt
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.graphics.context_instructions import LoadIdentity
from kivy.input import MotionEvent
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string("""
<Example>:
    orientation:"horizontal"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:"vertical"
        size_hint:0.5,1 # rate of win, this is menubar.
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 0, 0, 0.5, 1
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        Button:
            size:1,0.5
        Button:
            size:1,0.5
    FloatLayout:
        id: near_layout
        pos_hint:  {'x':0.5,'y':0}
        size_hint:0.5,1
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 0, 1, 0, 1
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        Image:
            id:img
            center: near_layout.center

            canvas.before:
                Rotate:
                    angle: root.angle
                    axis: 0,0,1
                    origin: self.center
            source: 'kivy.jpeg'
""")


class Example(App, BoxLayout):
    angle = NumericProperty(0)

    def build(self):
        Window.bind(on_resize=self.on_resize)
        return self

    def on_resize(self, obj, x, y):
        LoadIdentity()
        self.img = self.ids.img  # type:Image
        self.img.reload()  # Necessary,if not, image disappeared

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        self.angle += sqrt((touch.ppos[0] - touch.pos[0]) ** 2 + (touch.ppos[1] - touch.pos[1]) ** 2).real
        print("pos:%s,size:%s" % (self.ids.near_layout.pos, self.ids.near_layout.size))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Example().run()
```

Comment: Not 100% sure what you are asking, but making a couple small changes seems to make your app work more smoothly. I changed `center: near_layout.center` to `pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.5}`, and commented out the `Window.bind(on_resize=self.on_resize)` line. The resize seems to work fine without the `on_reize`.

Comment: Very thank you, John Anderson! Your indication gave the code my expected. I will try to implement your tips into my main project. If main program will work my expect, I am very glad.